# Validation that only allows a certain words

Tags: asp.net, regex, webmatrix

my last question was answered nicely, lets hope this one too :).

I am getting a very confusing error.I am using WebMatrix, asp.net and razor. Been following these tutorials. http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2.

I need a validation that will only accept certain words. such "Commerce" or "S7" "Science".
I can get it to only accept one word but when I enter another regEx statement, it accepts nothing.

```
Validation.RequireField("name", "Name is needed");
Validation.RequireField("surname", "Surname is needed");
Validation.RequireField("num", "num is needed");
Validation.RequireField("add", "add is needed");
Validation.RequireField("no", "no is needed");
Validation.RequireField("course", "course is needed");
Validation.RequireField("grade", "grade is needed");

Validation.Add("no", Validator.StringLength(10,10, "Contact number can not be longer or shoter than 10 digits"));
Validation.Add("num", Validator.StringLength(13,13,"Is number must be 13 digits"));
Validation.Add("name", Validator.Regex("^[a-zA-Z ]+$", "Invalid format for a name"));  
Validation.Add("grade", Validator.Range(8,12, "Grades must be between 8 and 12"));
Validation.Add("course", Validator.Regex("S7"+"Comm", "Course not valid"));
//Validation.Add("course", Validator.Regex("^Comm$", "Course not valid blah"));
```

Here is the rest of the code. Thanks in advance :)

```
@{  

    var db = Database.Open("ProjectTest");
    var Name = Request.Form["name"];
    var Surname = Request.Form["surname"];
    var IDNumber = Request.Form["num"];
    var Address = Request.Form["add"];
    var ContactNumber = Request.Form["no"];
    var Course = Request.Form["course"];
    var TechID = Request.Form["techID"];
    var grade = Request.Form["grade"];

    Validation.RequireField("name", "Name is needed");
    Validation.RequireField("surname", "Surname is needed");
    Validation.RequireField("num", "num is needed");
    Validation.RequireField("add", "add is needed");
    Validation.RequireField("no", "no is needed");
    Validation.RequireField("course", "course is needed");
    Validation.RequireField("grade", "grade is needed");

    Validation.Add("no", Validator.StringLength(10,10, "Contact number can not be longer or shoter than 10 digits"));
    Validation.Add("num", Validator.StringLength(13,13,"Is number must be 13 digits"));
    Validation.Add("name", Validator.Regex("^[a-zA-Z ]+$", "Invalid format for a name"));  
    Validation.Add("grade", Validator.Range(8,12, "Grades must be between 8 and 12"));
    Validation.Add("course", Validator.Regex("S7"+"Comm", "Course not valid"));
    //Validation.Add("course", Validator.Regex("^Comm$", "Course not valid blah"));

            if (IsPost){
                if (Validation.IsValid())
                {var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO UserInfo (Name, Surname, IdNum, Address, ContNum, Course, Grade)" + "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3 ,@4, @5, @6)";
                 db.Execute(insertQuery, Name, Surname, IDNumber, Address, ContactNumber, Course, grade);
                 }
                      }      
        else{
            ModelState.AddFormError("There are some errors with your submission"); 
        }  
   }


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/Home">Home</a><br>
              If you are an Student that wants to register use this form.<br>
       <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Surname:</td><td><input type="text" name="surname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>ID Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="num"><br></td>              
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="add"><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Contact Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="no"><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Course:</td><td><input type="text" name="course" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Grade:</td><td><input type="text" name="grade"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("name")<br>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("surname")<br>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("num")<br>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("add")<br>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("no")<br>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("course")<br>
           @Html.ValidationMessage("grade")
       </form>  
         <select name="courses">
        <option value="1" id="test">S7</option>
        <option value="2">Commerce</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the two that are in your code, try this:

```
Validation.Add("course", Validator.Regex("^S7$|^Comm$", "Course not valid"));
```

If you need to add more potential matches, just add them separated by pipe characters:

```
Validation.Add("course", Validator.Regex("^S7$|^Comm$|^Science$", "Course not valid"));
```

As you're using a database though, you should ask whether your data can be normalised better. Can courses be stored in a table and linked to, rather than stored as text? If you're following a tutorial this is probably outside the scope of what you're working on though, but you should bear it in mind for the future as it stops you having to validate data in this way at all.

For more information on regular expressions, have a look at this tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you :D! That worked great!! I now have a better understanding of Regular Expression